# Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail

I am not very good with email servers. Here is what I need:

I have a mailbox at fastmail.com with my custom domain (let's call it example.com). Now I want to set up my web server to relay emails through fastmail.com (I have their mx records in hand) and the no reply email address to be bot@example.com. I want to use sendmail to achieve this.

When I tried to send an email using sendmail, here is the log I got:

```
to=_myemailaddress_, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30088, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

(*myemailaddress* being my own email address).

The relay server here is 127.0.0.1, which doesn't seem right. So, I digged and found the two files /var/mail/submit.cf and /var/mail/sendmail.cf. Then I searched for the line with the text "127.0.0.1":

```
// submit.cf
FEATURE(`msp', `[127.0.0.1]', `25')dnl

// sendmail.cf
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
```

Should I change the addresses to fastmail MX records (in1-smtp.messagingengine.com, in2-smtp.messagingengine.com)?

Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail requires root privileges for some actions. Modern installations avoid being set root is by passing messages to sendmail daemon running with root privileges at 127.0.0.1:25.

Your local sendmail daemon does not seem to be up and running.

1. Check sendmail log files for any startup problems (log file names are OS/Distribution depended (e.g. `/var/log/mail.log` on Linux/Debian)
2. Start/restart sendmail daemon (procedure OS/Distribution dependent)

Comment: Thank you! I reatarted sendmail and relays are set up correctly. However, there is one more issue. The emails are going as root@example.com, which makes me think that the mails happen this way because the server is started on root. Is there a way to change this through sendmail config. Or should I create a new account with root privileges and run the server through them?

Comment: Have you tried to send email as non root user with the same effect?  Do you have public STATIC ip address?

Comment: Running from web sends it over www-data@exampld.com (the nginx user) but I want to have a different user for www-data without changing user's name to "bot". Yes I do have a static IP. It is on a server.

Comment: You have two choices: a) reconfigure your web-app to send emails as different user (Do you use php/....?) b) reconfigure sendmail to rewrite `www-data@exampld.com` email address in envelope sender and headers to another email address [It can be done using FEATURE(genericstable) - ask another question to get more details